# Expanding and Simplifying inner products with summation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

I am having trouble with a part of my assignment. I need to show that

$||x - P_Ex||^2$ = $||x||^2 - \sum_{j=1}^n |\langle e_j,x \rangle|^2$

where $e_j$ is in a hilbert space and an orthonormal set, and $P_Ex$ is the orthogonal projection of x onto E and is defined as

$P_Ex = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle e_i,x \rangle e_i$,
and
$ \langle e_j,e_i \rangle = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$

So far I have started by expanding the lefthand side and got this.

$||x - P_Ex||^2$ = $ \langle x, x\rangle - \langle x,P_Ex \rangle - \langle P_Ex,x \rangle + \langle P_Ex,P_Ex \rangle$

Since $P_Ex$ is orthogonal to x (I believe), the above line reduces to

$||x - P_Ex||^2$ = $ \langle x, x\rangle  + \langle P_Ex,P_Ex \rangle$

From here I would like to expand the last part

$\langle P_Ex,P_Ex \rangle = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle e_i,x \rangle e_i, \quad   \sum_{j=1}^n \langle e_j,x \rangle e_j \right\rangle$

I feel like this would result in a vector of vectors but I don't really understand how it would work exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sesquilinearity$$\langle P_Ex,\,P_Ex\rangle=\sum_{ij}\underbrace{\langle e_i,\,x\rangle}_{\overline{\langle x,\,e_i\rangle}}\langle x,\,e_j\rangle\underbrace{\langle e_i,\,e_j}_{\delta_{ij}}\rangle=\sum_j|\langle x,\,e_j\rangle|^2.$$Now use the same technique to show $\langle x,\,P_Ex\rangle=\sum_j|\langle x,\,e_j\rangle|^2$, so the final coefficient of $\sum_j|\langle x,\,e_j\rangle|^2$ is $-2+1=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

No, we don't have $P_Ex\perp x$ in general. Rather, $P_Ex\in E={\rm span}(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ and $(x-P_Ex)\perp E$.

Then, using the Pythagorean theorem, we get
$$\|x-P_Ex\|^2+\|P_Ex\|^2\ =\ \|(x-P_Ex)+P_Ex\|^2\ =\ \|x\|^2\,.$$
Which implies the statement when you substitute the value for $P_Ex$ only in the term $\|P_Ex\|^2$.

Comment: I don't understand the use of Pythagoreans theorem from the expansion of $||x - P_Ex||^2$. But it does make somewhat sense that $P_Ex $ is not orthogonal to x.

Comment: We have $a:=P_Ex$ and $b:=x-P_Ex$ then $a\perp b$ and the sum of their squares is the square of $a+b$.